# How include script only on certain time

Tags: php, if-statement, time

I want to include script only on certain time from **7:00AM** US time and turn off at **1:00PM** .

This is what I have:

```
date_default_timezone_set( 'America/New_York' );
$time = date( 'H' ); ?>
<script>console.log('<?php echo $time; ?>');</script>
<?php if($time >= 07 && $time <= 01) : ?>
    <script>alert("That works!");</script>
endif;
```

I understand that I'm trying to compare a larger number firstly, but don't understand what I need to do.

24-format doesn't work too.

Thanks!

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

Comment: Hi, @SarathSRajendran , I'm trying to include script <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/livechat.js"></script>

Comment: `>7` and `<1` will never match, you'd need two conditions for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set( 'America/New_York' );
$current_time = date('H:i a');
$US1 = "7:00AM";
$US2 = "1:00PM";
$date1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i a', $current_time);
$date2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i a', $US1);
$date3 = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i a', $US2);
if ($date1 > $date2 && $date1 < $date3)
{
   echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/livechat.js"></script>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use H in `date()` this gives the 24 hour format of the hour, so your test should probably be against 7 & 13...

```
<?php if($time >= 7 && $time <= 13) : ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished with timestamp comparison:

```php
date_default_timezone_set( 'America/New_York' );
if (strtotime(date('H:i')) >= strtotime('7:00') && 
    strtotime(date('H:i')) <= strtotime('13:00')) { /* do stuff */ }
```

To get 1pm you should use military time... it's 13 o'clock.

I recommend doing it this way instead of just comparing hours because if you wish to specify a different time in the future it is very flexible.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the time without leading zero like so:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
$hour = (new DateTime())->format('G');
?>
<script>console.log('<?php echo $time; ?>');</script>
<?php if ($hour >= 7 && $hour <= 13): ?>
<script>alert("That works!");</script>
<?php endif; ?>
```